# golang парсинг xml получить значение поля

Tags: xml, golang

Как теперь мне прочитать само значение поля (не атрибут)? Это где циферки =)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

var xmlContent = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <lists>
  <paragraph>
<list href="href12" listAtr="wwwww">2332</list>
<lists href="href13" listAtr="sssss">4554</lists>
<lists href="href21" listAtr="fffff">1111</lists>
<lists href="href22" listAtr="ggggg">1122</lists>       
  </paragraph>
  <paragraph>
<list href="href12" listAtr="wwwww">2332</list>
    <lists href="href13" listAtr="sssss">4554</lists>
    <lists href="href21" listAtr="fffff">1111</lists>
    <lists href="href22" listAtr="ggggg">1122</lists>       
  </paragraph>
</lists>
`

type lists struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name    `xml:"lists"`
    Paragraf []paragraph `xml:"paragraph"`
}

type paragraph struct {
    //XMLName  xml.Name
    ListTop  []List     `xml:"list"`
    ListsDoc []ListsStr `xml:"lists"`
}

type List struct {
    HrefList string `xml:"href,attr"`
    List     string `xml:"listAtr,attr"`
}

type ListsStr struct {
    HrefLists string `xml:"href,attr"`
    Lists     string `xml:"listAtr,attr"`
}

func main() {
    str := lists{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlContent), &str)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(str)
    fmt.Println("\n-------")
    for inx, _ := range str.Paragraf {
        fmt.Println("Top: ", str.Paragraf[inx].ListTop)
        for _, k := range str.Paragraf[inx].ListsDoc {
            fmt.Println("Doc", k)
        }
        fmt.Println("-------\n")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить в структуры List и ListsStr

Поле с атрибутом ",innerxml" или ",chardata", например

```
type ListsStr struct {
    HrefLists string `xml:"href,attr"`
    Lists     string `xml:"listAtr,attr"`
    Value    string `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/sIKjkn9pZ0

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal